# Checking disk file usage via CLI on Nitrous.IO

Tags: command-line-interface, nitrousio

Creating a basic Nitrous.IO box you are very limited on resources.  It's a habit of mine to check disk file usage via the linux shell command "df -h", however this gives incorrect output in Nitrous.IO.

Is there an alternative CLI command that can be used to check disk usage in the web based IDE for Nitrous.IO (that will provide data relevant to my box alone)?

Here is a sample of the output that "df -h" gives me:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on                                                                                                                                                  
/dev/root       500G  494G  6.4G  99% /                                                                                                                                                           
/run            6.7G   56K  6.7G   1% /run
```

My box only has 1000 MB of storage, and I can check the utilization by going to the box settings, but that requires me to exit the IDE (or have another browser tab opened during editing).  You can see a sample of this [here](http://help.nitrous.io/images/articles/box-settings-screen.png).  It would be much easier to check the usage in the CLI at the bottom of the IDE screen.

Thanks,
SirCobalt

Answer (score 1):

You can get the disk usage of your home directory:

```
du -h --max-depth=2 /home
```

Answer (score 0):

According to an earlier post, "they are working on it"
[Nitrous.IO - Installing rspec and it fails to install - An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143729/nitrous-io-installing-rspec-and-it-fails-to-install-an-error-occurred-while/21417062#21417062)

that was in November though.  Seem the only way to find this info currently though, is through the setttings page, with all the issues you just described.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks eremite, seams to be working also on Openshift Online.

```
du -h --max-depth=1
```

When invoked from the SSH just after login.