# Nitrous.IO - Installing rspec and it fails to install - An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rubygems, nitrousio

Here is the full error message I get

> Errno::ENOSPC: No space left on device - /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
>   An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.>

I'm following the Ruby on Rails 3 tutorial and hoping to see what the rspec testing does but Nitrous.IO application doesn't allow me to install it.

```
group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'webrat'
end
```

The error message obviously points to a space issue but I was hoping for a way round this? Or maybe that I have missed something else obvious. Do I simply just need to pay and get more space on Nitrous.IO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will make this easier to determine disk usage in the future, but for now the simplest way to see the disk space used is to navigate to your [boxes page](https://www.nitrous.io/app#/boxes), and from there clicking "Settings" within your box information.

If you want to see which specific folders are using up disk space, you can run the following command in your console:

View overall disk usage:

```
du --max-depth=1 -h ~/ | sort -g -r
```

If you ran out of space due to installing packages from Autoparts then you could delete the archives found in `~/.parts/archives`. Else, you may need to uninstall some gems if they appear to take up the majority of space.

You can also reconfigure your Nitrous box to include more space; take a look at the [upgrade guide](http://help.nitrous.io/upgrade-box/) for more information on that.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I woudl like to add, I just had that same issue and discovered two things: 1) it is not easy to determine quota available, but 2) the default setup for my Nitrous box did not use all the available diskspace I could use - I extended the disk and was able to proceed.  Depending on your configuration, you may just be able to extend the diskspace (I'm still on a free account, FYI)